Pass list of objects as argument in terraform helm_release
I have a variable list of objects tolerations, which I am trying to pass to helm_release terraform resource. The code block below is part of a module and I am importing that module in different place and using tolerations as an input.
locals {
  metabase_namespace   = "metabase-test"
}
    
resource "helm_release" "metabase-test" {
  name       = "metabase-test"
  namespace  = local.metabase_namespace
  repository = "https://pmint93.github.io/helm-charts"
  chart      = "metabase"
  version    = "2.14.4"
    
  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/templates/metabase-test.tpl", {
      tolerations = var.tolerations
    })
  ]
}
    
variable "tolerations" {
  type = list(object({
  key      = string
  operator = string
  value    = optional(string)
    effect   = optional(string)
  }))
  default = [{
    key      = "metabase"
    operator = "Equal"
    value    = "true"
    effect   = "NoSchedule"
  }]
}

and metabase-test.tpl
tolerations: ${tolerations}

I am trying to achieve this
tolerations:
  - key: metabase1
    operator: Equal
    value: "true"
    effect: NoSchedule
  - key: metabase2
    operator: Equal
    value: "true"
    effect: NoSchedule

I need to pass it through this specific variable given our setup, but cannot get it to render properly.

Marko E's answer is a simple and elegant solution.
If you want to have more control regarding the indentation and generated quotes " you can change your metabase-test.tpl like this:
tolerations:
%{ for toleration in tolerations ~}
  - key: ${ toleration.key }
    operator: ${ toleration.operator }
    value: ${ toleration.value }
    effect: ${ toleration.effect }
%{ endfor ~}

Generated output:
tolerations:
  - key: metabase1
    operator: Equal
    value: true
    effect: NoSchedule
  - key: metabase2
    operator: Equal
    value: true
    effect: NoSchedule


Or, as an alternative:
tolerations:
%{ for toleration in tolerations ~}
  - key: ${ chomp(yamlencode(toleration.key)) }
    operator: ${ chomp(yamlencode(toleration.operator)) }
    value: ${ chomp(yamlencode(toleration.value)) }
    effect: ${ chomp(yamlencode(toleration.effect)) }
%{ endfor ~}

Generated output:
tolerations:
  - key: "metabase1"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "true"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
  - key: "metabase2"
    operator: "Equal"
    value: "true"
    effect: "NoSchedule"


PS: chomp function removes the newline characters generated by yamlencode

Great stuff, I was thinking in terms of making the least changes possible, but this will work like a charm.

@MarkoE thanks, but your answer should probably be the accepted one. The advantage of my approach is that it's easier to understand the expected output, but on the other hand there's more code to maintain.

When using the templatefile built-in function to build a JSON/YML file, it's always a good idea to use the other available built-in functions like jsonencode/yamlencode, which you can find examples for in the documentation. The following snippet should be pasted in the metabase-test.tpl file, but I am still not sure if that would work:
${yamlencode({
    tolerations: [
        for toleration in tolerations: toleration
    ]
})}

This produces the following output:
"tolerations":
- "effect": "NoSchedule"
  "key": "metabase1"
  "operator": "Equal"
  "value": "true"
- "effect": "NoSchedule"
  "key": "metabase2"
  "operator": "Equal"
  "value": "true"

